# 'Manager' object is not iterable error

Tags: python, django, django-queryset

I'm trying to do a simple query, but I'm getting `'Manager' object is not iterable error.`

My code (relevant part):

```
def sort(request):
    sort_type = request.GET.get('srt', '')
    q = Question.objects
    if sort_type == 'views':
        q.order_by('-views')
    q.all()
    return render(request, 'questions/index.html',{
        'questions': q
    })
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your code should be

```
def sort(request):
    sort_type = request.GET.get('srt', '')
    q = Question.objects.all()
    if sort_type == 'views':
        q = q.order_by('-views')
    return render(request, 'questions/index.html',{
        'questions': q
    })
```

You need to assign `q.order_by('-views')` to `q` so you can update your queryset.

Comment: Correct if we are not using q.order_by() at least we have to use q.all() so that it will iterate over the rows